# nicEdit: edit with <p> instead of <div>

Tags: javascript, nicedit

How do I get nicEdit to use `<p>` tags in the editing area, instead of `<div>` tags?  Or, at least, change the default style of the `<div>` tag?

Comment: i would not use a p tag. you should consider using css to change the default style of the div.

Comment: I can change the div tags to p tags after the form has been submitted, so I can deal with div tags in the meantime.  Then I just need to know how to format the div tags to have paragraph spacing.